# How to convert from io.jsonwebtoken.Claims to java.util.Map<String,Object>?

Tags: java, maven, jwt, jjwt

I am working with `JWT` token using `io.jsonwebtoken` maven dependency.

> I am able to create a JWT token with custom payloads successfully.

Now while i am going to `parse` it, I need `Map<String, Object>` object **which has all those custom payloads which are added at the time of creation**, but unfortunately i am unable to complete it.

I am using following code to parse it,

```
JwtParser parser = Jwts.parser();
Claims claims = parser
                .setSigningKey(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(SIGN_KEY))
                        .parseClaimsJws(jwt).getBody();
```

Now, I have `io.jsonwebtoken.Claims` , but don't know how to convert this `io.jsonwebtoken.Claims` to `java.util.Map<String,Object>`

However I try with this to know(*almost looks similar which i want*) :-

```
System.out.println(claims.toString()); -> this is correctly prints whole custom payloads.
```

But i need `Map<String,Object>`

Any help will be appreciate..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Finally, i got the answer by listening my own - don't stop till get the answer,

```
public Map<String, Object>  getMapFromIoJsonwebtokenClaims(Claims claims){
    Map<String, Object> expectedMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    for(Entry<String, Object> entry : claims.entrySet()) {
        expectedMap.put(entry.getKey() , entry.getValue());
    }
    return expectedMap;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`io.jsonwebtoken.Claims` extends `java.util.Map<String, Object>`.

`io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultClaims`, the only provided implementation of `Claims`, is their implementation of Map, which decorates `LinkedHashMap<String, Object>` and adds a couple of methods.

So you should do nothing to convert to `Map`, because it is already `Map<String, Object>`.
If you'd like to get rid off their custom methods and convert `Claims` to `HashMap`, the shortest way is just pass `Claims` to the `HashMap`'s constructor. It does the same as you did manually.

```
Claims claims = ...; 

Map<String, Object> expectedMap = new HashMap<>(claims);
```